# Как лучше запрограммировать информацию о доступности теста в django

Tags: python, django

Пишу программу для проведения тестирования на Django. Есть вот такой класс:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Название теста", max_length=200)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, through='TestQuestion')
    published = models.BooleanField("Опубликован", default=False)
    interval = models.PositiveIntegerField("Время, через которое можно перепройти тест", default=0)
    #Метод проверяющий доступен ли тест для данного игрока
    def is_available(self, player):
        if not self.published:
            return False
        last_game = self.games.filter(player=player).order_by("-start_on").first()
        if not last_game:                
            return True
        if last_game.state == Game.OPEN:                
            return False
        interval = timedelta(seconds=self.interval)
        available_time = last_game.stop_on + interval
        if timezone.now() > available_time:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

У класса есть метод is_available, проверяющий доступен ли тест для игрока(так я называю человека, который будет проходить тест). Он будет вызываться в различных местах, н-р перед тем, как начать проходить тест.

Мне хотелось бы, чтобы кроме знания доступности теста, я как-то узнавал причину, по которой тест не доступен. Н-р, если не доступен из-за времени, то еще получить время, когда тест станет доступным (это хранится в available_time). Чтобы уведомить игрока, когда он сможет пройти тест. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое что пришло в голову:

1. возвращать кортеж типа `(result, reason)`, в котором в `result`
   будет содержать непосредственно `True` или `False`, а `reason` —
   причину (если она есть, если нет, то просто пустая строка или `None`),
   тогда ваша функция может выглядеть так:

   ```
   def is_available(self, player):
       if not self.published:
           return False, 'Еще не опубликован'
       last_game = self.games.filter(player=player).order_by("-start_on").first()
       if not last_game:                
           return True, None
       if last_game.state == Game.OPEN:                
           return False, 'Еще какая-то причина'
       interval = timedelta(seconds=self.interval)
       available_time = last_game.stop_on + interval
       if timezone.now() > available_time:
           return True, None
       else:
           return False, 'Тест станет доступен {0}'.format(available_time)
   ```

   Использовать тогда можно, например, так (`test` — некоторый тест,
   `player` соответственно некоторый игрок):

   ```
   result, reason = test.is_avaliable(player)
   if result == True:
       # код
   else
       print(reason)
       # ну или куда вы хотите это выводить
   ```

   Соответственно можно вернуть не строку, а непосредственно время или что-нибудь еще.
2. Можно сделать проще, и просто вместо `False` в вашей функции возвращать строку (такое решение подойдет только если в случае доступности теста вы не возвращаете ничего кроме `True`):

   ```
   if timezone.now() > available_time:
       return True
   else:
       return 'Тест станет доступен {0}'.format(available_time)
   ```

   Тогда вы также в проверках можете писать:

   ```
   result = test.is_avaliable(player)
   if (result == True):
       # код
   else: 
       print(result)
   ```
3. Можно еще просто выбрасывать исключение с текстом ошибки, если тест не доступен:

   ```
   class TestNotAvaliableException(Exception): # опишем собственный класс исключений
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.value)
   ```

   И функцию можно переписать так:

   ```
   def is_available(self, player):
       if not self.published:
           raise TestNotAvaliableException('Еще не опубликован')
       last_game = self.games.filter(player=player).order_by("-start_on").first()
       if not last_game:                
           pass
       if last_game.state == Game.OPEN:                
           raise TestNotAvaliableException('Еще какая-то причина')
       interval = timedelta(seconds=self.interval)
       available_time = last_game.stop_on + interval
       if timezone.now() > available_time:
           pass
       else:
           raise TestNotAvaliableException('Тест станет доступен {0}'.format(available_time))
   ```

   В таком случае функция просто не делает ничего, если тест доступен или выбрасывает исключение с текстом ошибки, если тест недоступен:

   ```
   try:
       test.is_avaliable(player)
   except TestNotAvaliableException as e:
       print(e)
       # ну и далее обрабатываете ситуацию, когда тест не доступен, например, выходите из функции или что-то в этом роде
   # а тут код, который должен сработать если тест доступен
   ```

   Хотя такой подход мне не нравится, так как если забыть об обработке исключения, вся программа повалится, да и вообще использовать исключения здесь кажется не самым красивым решением, но впринципе такой вариант тоже имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А мне 3 способ как раз наоборот понравился. Он самый гибкий. Он дает возможность обработать эти все случаи как-нибудь особенно. Если еще переименовать функцию в  check_available, то все вообще станет на свои места)

Comment: @A.N. не надо третий способ! Исключения нужны для обработки *исключительных* ситуаций, их не стоит использовать для управления логикой потока выполнения в штатном режиме. Я, например, когда бегло читаю чужой код, вообще пропускаю обработчики исключений.